# proof by mathematical induction n!< n^n

Tags: induction

"Let P(n) be the statement that (n)! < (n)^n, where is an integer greater than 1. Prove by mathematical induction that P(n) is true for all integers n greater than 1."

I've written

**Basic step**

*Show that P(2) is true:*

2! < (2)^2

1*2 < 2*2

2 < 4 (which is true)

*Thus we've proven that the first step is true.*

**Inductive hypothesis**

*Assume P(k) => ((k)! < (k)^k ) is true*

**Inductive step**

*Show that P(k+1) is true:*

(k+1)! < (k+1)^(k+1)

1*2*3*...*(k)*(k+1) < (k+1)*(k+1)*(k+1)*...*(k+1)

1*2*3*...*(k^2 + k ) < (k+1)*(k+1)*(k+1)*...*(k+1)

---

I'm not sure on how to continue from here...

Comment: Use the assumption that $P(k)$ is true

Comment: Too many parentheses! $(n)!$ is just $n!$, $(n)^n$ is just $n^n$...

Comment: Hint:  $n!<n^n\iff (n-1)!<n^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(k+1)^{k+1} = (k+1)\cdot(k+1)^{k} > (k+1)\cdot k^k>(k+1)\cdot k! = (k+1)!$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with $P(k)$.

$$k! < k^k$$

We want to show this implies $P(k+1)$. Perhaps multiplying both sides by $k+1$ will lead us closer to $P(k+1)$.

$$k! (k+1) < k^k (k+1).$$

Can you obtain $P(k+1)$ from here?